# Spark: join key-tuple pairs into key-list value

Tags: join, apache-spark, rdd, keyvaluepair

I have many RDDs ( let say 4 ) of this kind: K,(v1,v2,..,vN) and I have to join them, so I simply run

```
r1.join(r2).join(r3).join(r4)
```

The result will be something like K,((v1,v2,..,vN),(v1,v2,...,vN)),(v1,v2,...,vN))... and so on. Basically, I will get a nested structure of tuples, one for each join operation.

I was wondering if there exists a way to tell Spark to output as result of the join a union of the values of each RDD. In other words, I would like to get something like:

```
K, [ v1,v2,..., vN,v1,v2,..., vN,v1,v2,..., v1,v2,...,vN ]
```

Comment: 1) What language? 2) What are the types? 3) does order of values matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a multi-join or you could save yourself from nested syntax and apply a version of cogroup instead. However, since `cogroup()` only allows you to group up to 4 RDD's you can kind of monkey patch it to group more. Below is an example of a `multiCogroup()` function:

```
def multiCogroup[K : ClassTag, V : ClassTag](numPartitions: Int, inputRDDs: RDD[(K, V)]*) : RDD[(K, Seq[V])] = {
  val cg = new CoGroupedRDD[K](inputRDDs.toSeq, new HashPartitioner(numPartitions))
  cg.mapValues { case iterables => iterables.foldLeft(Seq[V]())(_ ++ _.asInstanceOf[Iterable[V]].toSeq) }
}
```

Run on an example, you can see the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1),("b", 2),("c", 3),("d", 4)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 4),("b", 3),("c", 2),("d", 1)))
val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("c", 0),("d", 0),("e", 0)))
val rdd4 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 5),("b", 5),("e", 5)))
val rdd5 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("b", -1),("c", -1),("d", -1)))

val combined = multiCogroup[String, Int](2, rdd1, rdd2, rdd3, rdd4, rdd5)
combined.foreach(println)

// (d,List(4, 1, 0, -1))
// (b,List(2, 3, 5, -1))
// (e,List(0, 5))
// (a,List(1, 4, 5))
// (c,List(3, 2, 0, -1))
```

*A few things to note*:

- If your input RDD value types are non-uniform, you could umbrella the output type `V` into type a super type (e.g. `Int` and `Long` into `Integral`, `String` and `Int` into `Any`). This might not be recommendable though as it could cause some ambiguity issues later on in your program. In general, I think the best use case of this is when all input value types are the same.
- I've defined the function to use a `HashPartitioner` with the number of partitions being the parameter `numPartitions`. It may make sense to tunnel your own Partitioner in by replacing the `numPartitions` argument. You can then pass the input partitioner directly to `CoGroupedRDD[K]()`, similarly done in the implementation of cogroup.
- I would probably apply some caution on using this method on large RDDs. Joins themselves can be kind of tricky depending on the size of the input data as well as the distribution of the key set. Expanding this to grouping multiple RDDs in a single cogroup could lead to similar memory issues quicker.